# Convert 2D dataframe to 3D based upon column names

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, multi-index

I have a dataframe with this shape:

```
hpa02upc00            hpa01upc01            hpa01upc00            hpa00upc02            hpa00upc01            hpa00upc00
pwr                                                                                                                                    
 0                      58.28                 58.23                 58.95                 58.09                 58.84                   NaN
-1                        NaN                   NaN                 58.16                   NaN                 58.06                 58.85
-2                        NaN                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN                 58.08
```

I want to turn it into a 3D data frame for filtering with the hpaXX value and the upcXX values as the new axis.

I am new to multiaxis and could use some help getting started on how to both extract the columns and regenerate the new dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: what is a 3D DataFrame? Can you provide the exact matching expected output? ALso please provide the DataFrame constructor for the input, it's currently unclear what is a column or index.

Comment: Can you provide the code to reproduce your data with: `df.head().to_dict()`? Looks like the column names are not properly aligned in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a multiindex after `extract`-ing the patterned strings from your column names:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract("(hpa.*)(upc.*)", expand=True), names=["hpa","upc"])

>>> df["hpa00"]
upc  upc02  upc01  upc00
pwr                     
 0   58.09  58.84    NaN
-1     NaN  58.06  58.85
 2     NaN    NaN  58.08

>>> df["hpa00"]["upc02"]
pwr
 0    58.09
-1      NaN
 2      NaN
Name: upc02, dtype: float64
```

##### Input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pwr": [0,-1,2],
                   "hpa02upc00": [58.28, None, None],
                   "hpa01upc01": [58.23, None, None],
                   "hpa01upc00": [58.95,58.16,None],
                   "hpa00upc02": [58.09,None,None],
                   "hpa00upc01": [58.84,58.06,None],
                   "hpa00upc00": [None,58.85,58.08],
                   })

df = df.set_index("pwr")
```